# X11 XQuartz 1.20.11 (xorg-server 1.20.11) on Big Sur fonts not recognized

Tags: font, x11, xquartz

I have `xset +fp the_directory` with TTF fonts, I have `mkfontdir` and `mkfontscale` the same directory, I have `fc-cache -fv` and verified the directory is listed and cached and font count correct, but `xlsfonts` continues to not list the TTF fonts I want added. Fonts I want are included in in the files `fonts.dir`, `fonts.scale` and `fonts.list`. I've verified the fonts I want are in Font Book in User.

I think I'm missing something pretty obvious, but can't seem to find it. How can I get TTF fonts made available for use by X11?

Comment: XQuartz 1.20.11?? The current release is 2.8.1: https://www.xquartz.org

Comment: Sorry, not XQuartz then - xorg-server, from MacPorts.

Comment: OK, same question - for _either_ xorg-server or XQuartz - neither show my added TTF fonts in xlsfonts.

Comment: Looks like no answers so far - I'd be interested to know if anyone's been able to add TTF fonts to either XQuartz or xorg-server in Big Sur successfully. Maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that xlsfonts does *not* list all fonts known, but rather either only the X server's fonts, or the fonts that are dealt with “classically”. `fc-list` will list the fonts that are dealt with in a more modern fashion (or that are on the X client?).

In the case of xterm, use the `-fa` flag to use TTF (and other non-bitmapped?) fonts. For example, if `xset q` shows directory X in the font path, and directory X has a fonts.dir file (made by running, e.g., `mkfontdir X`) and a fonts.scale file (made by running, e.g., `mkfontscale X`), and you've run `fc-cache -v`, you should be able to run (e.g.) `fc-list someFontName` and see all the styles that font contains, and be able to `xterm -fa 'Input Mono:style=Regular'`, assuming `Input Mono` is a known font.